# In Emacs org-mode, how to narrow display to two subtrees in two separate files?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I work with my frame split into two windows. I have two org-mode files open, each with subtrees I want to display in isolation.

I can do this successfully with a single subtree by navigating to Heading 1 in file-1.org and invoking the command `org-tree-to-indirect-buffer`.

But when I go to the second file in the second frame, navigate to the heading I want, and execute `org-tree-to-indirect-buffer on that tree`, it displays that subtree, BUT - in the first frame, it also unfocuses my subtree back to the main file.

How do I simultaneously view two subtrees in two separate files?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

## Narrowing

Try narrowing instead:

`(org-narrow-to-subtree)` : <kbd>C-x n s</kbd>

then

`(widen)` : <kbd>C-x n w</kbd>

when you're done

## org-tree-to-indirect-buffer

Alternatively, if you must use `org-tree-to-indirect-buffer`, it looks like you could also do this:

`(setq org-indirect-buffer-display 'current-window)`

<kbd>C-u M-x</kbd> `org-tree-to-indirect-buffer`

Where the normal action is to prevent buffer proliferation, but with the universal arg it will open a 2nd subtree without trashing the previous buffer.  Check <kbd>C-h f</kbd> `org-tree-to-indirect-buffer` for full details.